# Contact Picker People.Name,People.Number Error?

Tags: android

I want to get number from contacts in my project. I use this code http://www.androidsnippets.com/select-a-contact-from-the-from-address-book-using-people-provider-and-uri

What is People.Number or People.Name? Android doesnt accept it?

THX for advice.

Comment: Instead all off this stuff, you can use [contactslib](http://code.google.com/p/contactslib/)

Answer (score 0):

Now instead of `People.Number` or `People.Name`, `Phone.Number` or `Phone.Name` is used.